# SQL - 403 Forbidden | The request could not be processed because a function referenced by the SQL statement being evaluated is not accessible

Tags: sql

at the query below I get error 403 Forbidden and I can't find a solution. if I remove the part with CASE or the columns with SUM(+ GROUP BY) then it works, but I need all those columns.
I would be grateful if anyone could help me. thanks :-)

```
SELECT
    campaign_id,
    campaign_name,
    campaign_price,
    campaign_external_id,
    campaign_goal_adrequest,
    campaign_goal_banner_event,
    campaign_goal_banner_event_key,
    banner_id,
    banner_name,
    website_id,
    website_name,
    time_day,
    time_month,
    CASE
        WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'web_%' THEN 'web'
        WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'mob_%' THEN 'mob'
        WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'app_%' THEN 'app'
        WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'smart_%' THEN 'smart'
        ELSE 'others'
    END AS platform,
    SUM(measures_adrequests)    as adrequests,
    SUM(measures_views)         as views,
    SUM(measures_truecount)     as truecounts,
    SUM(events_4970_count)      as count_events,
    SUM(events_4453_visibility) as visibility_events,
    SUM(vast_click)             as click_events,
    SUM(vast_impression)        as vast_impressions,
    SUM(vast_start)             as vast_start,
    SUM(vast_firstquartile)     as vast_firstquartile,
    SUM(vast_midpoint)          as vast_midpoint,
    SUM(vast_thirdquartile)     as vast_thirdquartile,
    SUM(vast_complete)          as vast_complete,
    SUM(vast_loaded)            as vast_loaded
FROM
    MV_ADI_SUPERVIEW
WHERE
    campaign_id = :campaign_id
GROUP BY
    campaign_id,
    campaign_name,
    campaign_price,
    campaign_external_id,
    campaign_goal_adrequest,
    campaign_goal_banner_event,
    campaign_goal_banner_event_key,
    banner_id,
    banner_name,
    website_id,
    website_name,
    time_day,
    time_month,
    platform
```

Comment: Probably contentunit_name is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `Group By`, there is no reference to `contentunit_name` at all.

In fact, you should probably group by the entire "case" statement:

```
...
GROUP BY
CASE
    WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'web_%' THEN 'web'
    WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'mob_%' THEN 'mob'
    WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'app_%' THEN 'app'
    WHEN contentunit_name LIKE 'smart_%' THEN 'smart'
    ELSE 'others'
END,
campaign_id,
campaign_name,
campaign_price,
campaign_external_id,
campaign_goal_adrequest,
campaign_goal_banner_event,
campaign_goal_banner_event_key,
banner_id,
banner_name,
website_id,
website_name,
time_day,
time_month,
platform
```

The error message is confusing, tho. Are you using Oracle? How are you calling this query? (Please tag your question more specifically.)

Comment: yes i use oracle. and yes, your answer is my solution, I didn't know that I have to use "case" in "group by". thanks a lot

Comment: @svtl when you use aggregate functions (like Sum or Avg), you have to group by everything that isn't wrapped in those functions. Otherwise, the query won't run.